# Expect script for rsync with quotation marks

Tags: linux, bash, tcl, expect, rsync

I want to rsync a folder to another machine. sshpass is not an option and certificates don't either. So I'm stuck with expect.

So far, I have this bash script (minimized).

```
read -p "Enter remote IP: " IP
read -p "Enter remote user: " USER
read -s -p "Enter remote password: " PASSWORD
expect <<EOF
    set timeout -1
    spawn rsync -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" \
        -aHv --exclude=".*/" --delete ../.. ${USER}@${IP}:~/destination
    expect "password: "
    send "${PASSWORD}\n"
    expect eof
EOF
```

Problem is that rsync doesn't respect the "--exclude" option.
In the stdout, I see:

```
spawn rsync -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -aHv --exclude=".*/" --delete ../.. pi@10.0.1.2:~/OberonHAP
```

Somehow, the quotes around the -e option vanished, but exclude still has them.

So I escape the quotes

```
expect <<EOF
    set timeout -1
    spawn rsync -e \"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null\" \
        -aHv --exclude=".*/" --delete ../.. ${USER}@${IP}:~/destination
    expect "password: "
    send "${PASSWORD}\n"
    expect eof
EOF
```

but now I get

```
Missing trailing-" in remote-shell command.
```

Note that the command itself works perfectly when typed directly into a Terminal.

I've also tried different things, like 'EOF' heredoc and passing in the variables via environment, but always get error messages of different sorts :-)

**How do I have to escape the rsync command so that it works fine?**

Comment: Doesn't work even on 1 line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl's syntax (and hence Expect's syntax) is not the same as that of the shell. In particular, the quoting rules are different; you don't need to put double-quoting in the middle of a word as Tcl doesn't expand glob characters for you (you'd need to call `glob` explicitly if you wanted that). This means that your `spawn` command is actually best written as:

```
spawn rsync -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" \
    -aHv --exclude=.*/ --delete ../.. ${USER}@${IP}:~/destination
#                ☝☝☝☝☝☝ LOOK HERE!
```

Comment: You can omit the comment if you want…